# Showing equivalence under central symmetry - Complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider the function $h(z) = z^2 + z$, for$ z ∈ C$.
>
> Describe all $z$ such that $h(z) ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that for $z_1,z_2 ∈ \mathbb{C}$, $h(z_1) = h(z_2) \space $  iff 
>   $ \space z_2$ is the image of $z_1$ under a central symmetry in
>   $-\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> Now show that $h$ is a bijection from  $ \left \{ \space z \space |
> > \space Im(z) > 0 \right \}       ∪ [-\frac{1}{2}, ∞)$ onto
>   $\mathbb{C}$.

**So far I think I've figured this much out:**

if $z = a+bi$, then $h(z) = a^2-b^2+2abi + a + bi$.

Therefore $b=0$ or $a = -\frac{1}{2}$

On the central symmetry $| h(z_1)+\frac{1}2{} | = | h(z_2)+\frac{1}2{} |$.

I'm kind of stuck after this. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that for $z_1,z_2 ∈ \mathbb{C}$, $h(z_1) = h(z_2) \space $  iff 
>   $ \space z_2$ is the image of $z_1$ under a central symmetry in
>   $-\frac{1}{2}$.

$h(z_1) = h(z_2)$ means $z_1^2+z_1=z_2^2+z_2$

Thus, you can make $z_1^2-z_2^2=z_2-z_1$ and when $z_1\neq z_2$, $z_1+z_2=-1$ which means $z_1+\frac{1}{2}=-(z_2+\frac{1}{2})$